# Strip BBCode via RegEx

Tags: php, parsing, bbcode

I am trying to setup a regex that will detect [quote]???[/quote] and will remove it.

This is what I have but it is not working:

```
$post['body'] = preg_replace("/\[quote\](.+?)\[\/quote\]/is", '', $post['body']);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I also want to remove any line brakes before or after the [quote]???[/quote].

Comment: Just figured it out: `$post['body'] = preg_replace("/\[quote\](.+?)\[\/quote\]/is", '', $post['body']); $body = trim(rtrim($post[0]['body']));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out my own issue.

`$post['body'] = preg_replace("/\[quote\](.+?)\[\/quote\]/is", '', $post['body']);`
`$body = trim(rtrim($post[0]['body']));`

Comment: trim() will remove spaces on both sides of a string. So there is no need to add another rtrim.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my test with your script:

```
$text = "I am trying to setup a regex that will detect [quote]???[/quote] and will remove it.\r\nThis is what I have but it is not working:";
$sentences = preg_replace("/\[quote\](.+?)\[\/quote\]/is", '', $text);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($sentences, true).'</pre>';
```

And my Output:

```
I am trying to setup a regex that will detect  and will remove it.
This is what I have but it is not working:
```

You can see: [quote]???[/quote] is removed.

I think your problem is anywhere else. Check the Value of $post['body']!

Maybe it is a misspelling and you meen $_POST['body']?