# Strip string of anything inside pointy brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have a string, for example:

```
$string = '[caption]text text[/caption] Hello';
```

And I want remove anything within the brackets and the brackets as well so that the string will be:

```
$string = ' Hello';
```

In PHP, what would be the best way to do this? What regex should I use?

Comment: Regex. Regex would be the best way to do this.

Comment: It's equivalent to BBCode, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777257/remove-bbcode-tags-and-their-content-in-php

Comment: Try making a regex, post it, and we'll help you correct it.

Comment: Operating system > find mouse pointer > find browser > turn browser on > go to google > look for "regex php text between tags" > copy solution > profit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your BBcode tags are balanced and not nested, you can use a trivial pattern like the one suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759265/strip-bbcode-via-regex), adapted to all kind of tags:

```
$string = '[caption]text text[/caption] Hello';
$string = preg_replace('~\[(\w+)[^]]*].*?\[/\1]~si', '', $string);
```

Nothing difficult here, `(\w+)` captures the name of the tag, and `\1` is a reference to the capture.

However, several bbcode flavours accept self closing tags like `[*]` for items of a list, and tags can be nested:

```
[caption]text [i]text[/i] text[/caption]
[LIST][*]item1[*]item2[/LIST]
[img]http://img.com/image.jpg[/img] <-- common syntax
[img=http://img.com/image.jpg] <-- self-closing syntax
```

There are two possible solutions to remove them:

1) a solution with several pass:

- You must remove first self-closing tags: 
  `$str = preg_replace('~\[(?:\*|img=[^]]*)]~i', '', $str);`
- then in a while loop you remove the innermost balanced tags with their content, until there is nothing more to remove:
  `do {
  $str = preg_replace('~\[(\w+)[^]]*][^[]*\[/\1]~i', '', $str, -1, $count);
  } while ($count);`

2) with a recursive pattern in one pass:

```
$pattern = '~
# subpattern definitions
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<scTag> \[ (?:\* | img=[^]]* ) ] ) # self-closing tags
    (?<bTag> \[(\w+)[^]]*] [^[]* (?: \g<Tag> [^[]* )*+ \[/\g{-1}] )
    (?<Tag> \g<scTag> | \g<bTag> )
)

# main pattern
\g<Tag>+
~xi';

$str = preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lP3zV1/1)

Note: to be more rigorous, you can replace `\w+` with the names of the bbcode tags: `(?:caption|font|[bis]...)`.

Comment: This is absolutely lovely, thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a function `stripTag(String fullstr, String tagname)` :

call it like this: `stripTag('[caption]asdf[/caption] hello', 'caption')`

search for [tagName] and [/tagName]. build a new string using substr with the parts of the input before & after the search area you found.